# Save audio from RTP stream that contains RFC 2833 RTP events

Tags: voip, wireshark, rtp

I'm trying to extract audio from a telephone session captured with Wireshark.  The capture as send to us from the telephone provider for debugging/analysis. I have 3 files: signalling, and two files with UDP data, one for each direction. After merging two of these files (one direction with signalling), Wireshark provides RTP stream analysis. What I observe (as I do for a second session capture) is that Wireshark isn't able to export RTP stream audio (`Payload type: ITU-T G.711 PCMA (8)`) for one direction. This happens to be an RTP stream containing "RTF 2833 RTP events" (`Payload type: telephone-event (106)`). These events seem to transport DTMF tunes out-of-band, for each DTMF tune, there is a section of 7 consecutive RTP events of this type. What Wireshark does is producing an 8 GB *.au file for an audio stream less than two minutes. For the opposite-direction stream I get an audio file that is 2 MB in size.

[image]

I have to admit that this is just guesswork: I connect the error with a feature that I can see, I'm a bit confused that Wireshark obviously *knows* these Events but fails on saving the corresponding audio stream. Do I maybe need some plugin for that?

I tried to search the web for this issue but without success.

---

<sub>This question was previously asked on Network Engineering but turned out to be off-topic there.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can filter (rtp.p_type != 106) the DTMF events from the wireshark logs (pcap) and then save only the G.711 data in a separate file.

Then do the RTP analysis and save the audio payload in .au/.raw file format.

Comment: If I save audio from the filtered view, I get the same 8 GB au file. If I save the filtered packets and load it next, it's displayed as a stream of UDP packets. Is there a way to filter out only those RTP packets that have PT=106?

Comment: If I filter by `!(rtp.p_type==106)` I get the right selection. I can save and reload the audio stream in this way, so filtering seems reasonable. But exporting audio leads to the same result: an 8 GB au file. Now I have the feeling that's just a bug.

Comment: There is a option Decode As - select the protocol as RTP.

Comment: Tell me how many total packets are present with each SSRC, based on it I can calculate the file size.

Comment: In the RTP stream analysis, I see that the duration is 111.78 seconds, the other direction which I can save successfully has 105.16 seconds and an au file size of 1.940 KB. In another case, I have an audio stream of 139.37 s duration and get the same obviously wrong file size of 8.0 GB. It's **5140 RTP packets** with `Payload type: ITU-T G.711 PCMA (8)`, with a payload size of 159 Bytes. Sorry if I'm misunderstanding you: I'm an absolute beginner on the VoIP planet.

Comment: Total No of RTP packets : 5140  X Payload Size of G.711 : 160 bytes = 822400 bytes . You file size should be approx 800 KB/0.8 MB. Please check again.

Comment: I'm sure about the 8 GB size, I have to wait for the Wireshark GUI to get responsive again (it's not possible to kill the process while "saving"), I tried lots of exports. I *know* that I'm getting constantly 8 GB for streams like that. It's an RTP type 8 stream with RTP type 106 packets (always 7 consecutive of them) integrated. The sequence numbers continuously increase during the stream regardless of the changes in the payload type.

Comment: Can you share me the filtered pcap file. Please can you check on different version of wireshark ( might be there is a bug in the version you are using)

Comment: I can not share the pcap file, sorry. I now tried the same with version 2.6.10 of Wireshark (all previous testing was done with version 3.0.3). I'm getting the same result. BTW: using VLC, I hear that the file contains the expected audio at the beginning. After that there seemed to be only silence for 149 hours. I took the burden on myself to wait until Audacity had loaded the file (half an hour), now I *know* that the rest is silence.

Comment: I think you can raise this issue in wireshark forum. I had never faced such issues, i am using Wireshark Version 2.0.4